# MySQL select with count

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table of users I have column with name "query" which means how many times user press SEARCH button.

So for example I have:

```
login | query | company
user1 |   40  |    1
user2 |   60  |    1
user3 |   30  |    2
```

What I try is to get number of queries of all users in one company. I already tried something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as total_count FROM users WHERE company = :company";
```

But this just gives me the number of people from one company and I'm not sure how can I edit it to count all queries together.

Comment: Instead of `count(*)`, which will just count the number of results, you want to use `sum(query)`, which will give you the total of all the values of the `query` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `group by` the company and `sum` the number of queries:

```
SELECT   company, SUM(query) as total_count
FROM     users
GROUP BY company
```

Comment: I think the table is called users.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION database_name.SUN does not exist

Comment: @Andurit you typed `SUN`, with an **N** instead of `SUM` with an **M**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(query) as total_count FROM users group by company
```

Comment: How will you know which sum belongs to which company?